# Code for time subtraction

Tags: vba, excel

```
If Left(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(y, 8), 11) >= "12:00:00" Then
     word5 = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(y, 8), 11) - TimeValue(Now)
```

Here are my codes to subtract current time with Column H cells.
The result of this coding is in 0.69694444444444 , How can I get it to be in hours?

Comment: We are not here to produce code for you. Please post your code and ask specific question on what you do not understand, so we can help you understanding, what you currently do not understand.

Comment: Is this a vb.net application (created in Visual Studio) or a vba macro (created in Excel)? They are not the same thing. If it is a vba macro, please edit your question to delete the vb.net tag.

Answer (score 0):

`TimeValue()` returns a Double and `Left()` returns a Variant containing a String, so I'm surprised that this works at all.  You should be getting a type mismatch with this:

```
word5 = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(y, 8), 11) - TimeValue(Now)
```

You need to explicitly cast to Date types:

```
Dim time As Date, result As Date
time = CDate(Left(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(y, 8), 11))
result = time - TimeValue(Now)
Debug.Print result
```

Note that there's also an error in your If condition - you're performing a text based comparison. Consider the fact that...

```
Debug.Print "10:00:00 PM" > "11:00:00 AM"
```

...results in False. You should be doing *all* date/time comparisons with either Doubles or Dates.

Comment: If result >= "01:00:00" Then
      ax = ax + 1                  word4 = word4 & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(y, 2) & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(y, 5)
     UserForm1.Label10.Caption = word4 UserForm1.Label11.Caption = ax  here i want to display word4 only when the result is greater than 1hr

Comment: so can you help me out to make the necessary changes in here